# Clear File Explorer settings (position, size etc.)

Tags: windows

Is it possible to clear the Windows File Explorer position, preferences, size etc. to the default settings?

Answer (score 2):

Windows (File) Explorer view settings are stored in multiple locations.

Try the tutorial on the following page: 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15692-folder-view-settings-reset-all-default.html

The following batch script is part of the tutorial demonstrating these locations.

```
@echo off

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15692-folder-view-settings-reset-all-default.html


:: To reset all folders to default folder views
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F


:: To kill and restart explorer
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: This dose not clear window position...